# Como manter a assinatura do email remetente ao usar a função Mail::send() no laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, email

Eu consigo enviar o email corretamente mas, o email vai sem assinatura do email remetente, e não estou encontrando como resolver.

```
$emails = ['teste@gmail.com', 'teste2@gmail.com.br'];
$copias = ['teste3@gmail.com', 'teste4@hotmail.com'];

Mail::send('dashboard.teste', ['curso' => 'Eloquent'], function($m) use ($emails,  $assunto, $copias)
{    
        $m->to($emails)->subject($assunto)->from("remetente@gmail.com", "Remetente")->cc($copias, "email cópia");    
});
```

Código da dashboard.teste

```
teste {{$curso}}
```

Comment: não entendi bem o que quis dizer com "manter assinatura do email remetente", pode me explicar?

Comment: Meu email tem uma assinatura com meu nome, telefone e email por exemplo, o email enviado via aplicação utilizando esta função vai sem a assinatura. Deu pra entender?

Comment: @Lorena por favor atualiza a pergunta e colocar a blade `dasborad.teste`

Comment: @Bulfaitelo atualizada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao que entendi você esta esperando que o `Mailer` identifique a assinatura configurada no seu servidor e inclua também em cada envio pelo fato de você estar usando o mesmo SMTP/POP certo?

O `Mailer` **não identifica a assinatura que você configurou no servidor automaticamente** *(não sei se isso é possivel)*, então você precisa incluir a informação no template explicitamente, veja:

Template email:

```
Curso: {{ $curso }}



{{ $nomeAssinatura }} - Setor
Nome da Empresa
Endereço
Phone: {{ $telefone }}
```

Controller:

```
$emails = ['teste@gmail.com', 'teste2@gmail.com.br'];
$copias = ['teste3@gmail.com', 'teste4@hotmail.com'];
$emailInfo = [
    'curso' => 'Eloquente' ,
    'nomeAssinatura' => 'Lorena',
    'telefone' => $telefone
];

Mail::send('dashboard.teste', $emailInfo, function($m) use ($emails,  $assunto, $copias)
{    
    $m->to($emails)->subject($assunto)->from("remetente@gmail.com", "Remetente")->cc($copias, "email cópia");    
});
```

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigada, vou tentar essa solução.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigada pela ajuda!